# Owl reasoners that can use multiple cpus

Tags: owl, ontology, reasoning

Are there OWl reasoners except ELK that can use multiple cpu well? I have a python Program that need like 3000+ classifications , so at best the owl reasoner works with cmd command or with python directly and works well with parallelism.

Comment: what means "3000 classifications"? What is a single classification in your context? Note, usually the expression "classification" means the problem of identifying the subsumption relationships between all pairs of classes in the input ontology.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/konclude/Konclude

Comment: What I meant from classification , is classifiying the classes (consistant/ unconsistant) .@Ignazio For Konclude , it was my first try as a reasoner . It didnt work any faster on a HPC .. Do you have any experience with it ?